# How to get rid of 'dot' in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to get rid of 'dot' after the end of the sentence or move the dot with the space  e.g  `'I like dogs.'` into `'I like dogs or i like dogs .'`

Will this code be correct?

```
.gsub(".", "  ")
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try `"I like dogs."[0..-2]`

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to get rid of it at the end of the sentence the most rubyish way would be:

```
a = 'I like dogs.'
p a.chomp('.') #=> "I like dogs"
#modify a by using:
a.chomp!('.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to update the dot if and only it’s trailing in the whole sentence. `gsub` approach won’t work as is here, since it will substitute all the appearances of dots everywhere.

The regular expression would do, though:

```
input = 'I like dogs.'
input.sub(/\.\z/, '') #⇒ to get rid of it
input.sub(/\.\z/, ' .') #⇒ to insert a space before it
```

`\z` matcher here matches the end of the string.

To substitute all the dots in the string:

```
input.delete('.') #⇒ to get rid of it
input.gsub('.', ' .') #⇒ to insert a space
```

Comment: Actually I need to apply it into whole text so has to be gsub. The correct then will be .gsub(".", "  .") ?

Comment: What is the problem with _testing your approach_? Yes, to apply this change to the whole text, `gsub('.', ' .')` would be fine.